# How to show cursor position when dragging block element just like drag img and selected text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I got a draggable block element in contentEditable body element like this:

`<body contentEditable='true'><p draggable id='drag'>some text here</p><p id='text'>another text</p></body>`

And I want to drag `p` element into `p[id=text]`, just as drag `img` element, when we dragging draggable element there would be a cursor showing during `p[id=text]` text (in this case) to indicate the position where draggable element should insert in.

So my main question is: How to show cursor when dragging block element into some text just like drag `img` element? Is there any possibility to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the `dragEvent.dataTransfer` to the textContent of your element and use the Non-standard `user-select` CSS property to avoid selecting text instead of dragging the element. Also, for chrome, you have to set your draggable element's contenteditable property to `false`.

```js
document.querySelector('p').addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", this.textContent);
}, false);
```

```css
#drag{
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none; 
    -ms-user-select: none; 
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<body contentEditable='true'>
  <p contenteditable="false" draggable="true" id='drag'>some text here</p>
  <p id='text'>another text</p>
</body>
```

Comment: I have test the code and it is almost exactly what I want! But there is a small problem: if  ```img``` element in  ```p``` element I want to drag, ```e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", this.textContent);``` seems to be not working well, as both of ```img``` and text in ```p``` should be move to destination. How can I fix that?

Comment: Hmm, in that case, you should save the dragged element in a global variable, and in the drop event of your `#text` element, insert a clone or first remove the dragged from its parent then insert it back in your target element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragstart#Example

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're asking for? The code below shows the position of the mouse cursor

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $('#printerX').html('X : ' + e.pageX + "px");
    $('#printerY').html('Y : ' + e.pageY + "px");
  });
});
```

```css
body
{
  background-color: #E1E7E8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Move your mouse in the HTML document</h2>
<p id="printerX"></p>
<p id="printerY"></p>
```

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I didn't make my question clear: when we dragging ```img``` element or selected text (cause both of them are draggable by default) into another text, and we can move cursor to select where to insert ,since browser will show cursor position (flicker cursor) at that time. So is there any possibility to achieve the same effect to drag draggble block element (show flicker cursor)?